# Android: Not able to make a lot of activities of the same types

Tags: java, android

I have a class `YNActivity` which extends `Activity`. I want to make more activities of this type by pressing the button `btnYNNext`. I have put a following code in this class.

```
 public class YNActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

`TextView YNTextView;
Button btnYNNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yn);
    YNTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.YNTextView);
    YNTextView.setText("Task");
    btnYNNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnYNNext);
    btnYNNext.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()){
      case R.id.btnYNNext: {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(YNActivity.this);
        View ynPage = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_yn, null);
        setContentView(ynPage);
      }
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }
 }
}`

But when I run my project and press the button a new activity is shown only once. Does anyone know of a good way to make a lot activities of same types?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not creating new activity. You should use `Intent` and `startActivity` method to create new activities.

I strongly recommend you to read documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnYNNext:
            Intent intent = new Intent(YNActivity.this, YNActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```